# How to properly develop pagination on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to achieve some pagination but I am getting an error.

The pagination max size is set to 10 items per page.

I have an array of 17+ items, when the component mounts, it loads the first 10 items properly, if I go to the next page it loads the next items properly too, but when I get back to the previous page, it loads 12 items. Like, every time I go back/next page, it loads 2 more items.

This is what I have:

```
const PAGINATION_PAGE_SIZE_DEFAULT = 10;

class ApaTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      headers: this.props.headers,
      data: this.props.data,
      page: 1,
      pageSize: PAGINATION_PAGE_SIZE_DEFAULT
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { data, headers } = nextProps;

    this.setState({ data: data.slice(0, this.state.pageSize), headers });
  }


  onPaginationChange = e => {
    let pageNumber = e.page;
    let pageSize = e.pageSize;
    let start = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;
    let end = pageNumber * pageSize;

    this.setState({
      data: this.props.data.slice(start, end),
      page: pageNumber,
      pageSize
   });
  }

  render() {
    const { data, headers } = this.state;

    console.log({ STATE_DATA: data });

    return (
     <>
        <DataTable
          rows={data}
          headers={headers}
          render={({ rows, headers, getRowProps, getTableProps }) => (...)} >...</DataTable>
        <PaginationV2
          totalItems={data.length}
          pageSize={PAGINATION_PAGE_SIZE_DEFAULT}
          pageSizes={[10, 20, 30]}
          onChange={this.onPaginationChange}
        />
     <>

    )
  }

}
```

This is the component I am using: http://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/story/pagination--pagination

So I guess it is something in the slice method which is not working properly or probably the state.

Within the render method I have this `console.log({ STATE_DATA: data });` and it shows the amount of items every time I change the page, but the table keeps getting more and more items if I do the back and forth I mentioned.

What could I be missing?

This is the datatable component I am using -> http://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/story/datatable--default

And pagination -> http://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/story/pagination--pagination

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like this,Don't change the data directly then you will lose all other data for the pagination, Keep the `tableData` seperatly.

```
const PAGINATION_PAGE_SIZE_DEFAULT = 10;

class ApaTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      headers: this.props.headers,
      data: this.props.data,
      tableData: this.props.data.slice(0, PAGINATION_PAGE_SIZE_DEFAULT),
      page: 1,
      pageSize: PAGINATION_PAGE_SIZE_DEFAULT
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { data, headers } = nextProps;

    this.setState({ tableData: data.slice(0, this.state.pageSize), data, headers });
  }


  onPaginationChange = e => {
    let pageNumber = e.page;
    let pageSize = e.pageSize;
    let start = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;
    let end = pageNumber * pageSize;

    this.setState({
      tableData: this.props.data.slice(start, end),
      page: pageNumber,
      pageSize
   });
  }

  render() {
    const { tableData, headers } = this.state;

    console.log({ STATE_DATA: tableData });

    return (
     <>
        <DataTable
          rows={tableDate}
          headers={headers}
          render={({ rows, headers, getRowProps, getTableProps }) => (...)} >...</DataTable>
        <PaginationV2
          totalItems={data.length}
          pageSize={PAGINATION_PAGE_SIZE_DEFAULT}
          pageSizes={[10, 20, 30]}
          onChange={this.onPaginationChange}
        />
     <>

    )
  }

}
```

Comment: It keeps loading the 2 more items ever time I go back and forth.

Comment: Could you please check the `tableData` in each page change.

Comment: Yeah. It is weird because it changes fine. I can see `tableData` holding 7 items but the table renders 9. It only renders 7 items the first time I go to the second page, but the second time I go to the second page, it renders 9 items.

Comment: It can't happen, Could you please check the is `DataTable` referring `tableData`?

Comment: Yeah I know it can't happen. It should a bug with the component.